# Apache ProxyRemote random server - more than one server possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, httpd

I am using mod_proxy for my forward proxy server and I would like to use another proxy using ProxyRemote. It works OK, the point is I have 5 more proxies I would like to use that way and I can set just one of them in httpd.conf

Do you know a way to dynamically select random proxy ip and use for each request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [round-robin DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) to serve up a different one of the 6 IP addresses for your proxy hostname, every time it's used.

Basically the technique is just to define multiple A records for your hostname.  The records will then get served in order as requests come in, giving a rotating set of results.  See for example the [load balancing section of the Zytrax DNS book](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/rr.html).  But you should check with your DNS provider to be sure.

Comment: It looks like good idea. Can you give some example ? 
Can I just add those 6 proxy IPs to my local DNS configuation file under the same domain ?
Should I use some external domain or some local will be enough ?
Thank you for the idea.

Comment: Yes, that's what you do.  I added more information.

Comment: thanks. added them to localdomain.zone file.
then restarted named - nothing happened.
had to do - rndc reload, after just one IP was used for proxy.localdomain.
had to add - rrset-order {order random;}; to named.conf options.
now is good.

Comment: I have just one problem with this setup.
I have many proxies set in localdomain.zone file , all of them as A record but when I test it , it always uses just one subnet, I think the closest to my server ip.
Any idea how to set DNS not to match the closest subnet and use all IPs I have assigned to http://proxy.localdomain ?